# CURL POST request in VB.NET (json)

Tags: .net, vb.net

I've been struggling to send this CURL request in VB.NET and hope someone can help..

[Here is a link to the documentation](https://www.name.com/api-docs/domains#CreateDomain) of the exact request I'm trying to send.

This is the sample CURL request:

```
curl -u 'username:token' 'https://api.dev.name.com/v4/domains' -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{"domain":{"domainName":"example.org"},"purchasePrice":12.99}'
```

Here is the code that I put together and tested:

```
Dim uri As New Uri("https://api.dev.name.com/v4/domains")
Dim myUsername As String = txtUsername.Text.Trim & ":" & txtApiKey.Text.Trim
Dim data As String = "{""domain"":{""domainName"":""example.org""},""purchasePrice"":12.99}"
Dim dataByte As Byte()

request = WebRequest.Create(uri)
request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Basic " & Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myUsername)))
request.ContentType = "application/json"
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
request.Method = "POST"

dataByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data)
request.GetRequestStream.Write(dataByte, 0, dataByte.Length)

Dim myResp As HttpWebResponse
myResp = request.GetResponse()
Dim myreader As New System.IO.StreamReader(myResp.GetResponseStream)
WebResponse = myreader.ReadToEnd()

MsgBox(WebResponse)
```

However, the code above always returns a (400) Bad Request. I even tried adding a UserAgent in there to see if that would help, but it's the same both with and without it. The CURL request seems pretty simple - Authorization, One Header (content type) and the data. Can't really figure out where I'm going wrong here since I'm converting the user details, including the content type in the header, and when I look at my data string it matches their example perfectly. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I've tried several different variations of the code in this post. Here is another variation of pretty much the same code which I tried, it also gives the same thing: 400 (Bad Request)

```
Dim myReq As HttpWebRequest
Dim myResp As HttpWebResponse
Dim myUsername As String = "username:token"

myReq = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://api.dev.name.com/v4/domains")

myReq.Method = "POST"
myReq.ContentType = "application/json"
myReq.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " & Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myUsername)))

Dim myData As String = "{""domain"":{""domainName"":""example.org""},""purchasePrice"":12.99}"
Dim dataBytes As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myData)
myReq.GetRequestStream.Write(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length)

myResp = myReq.GetResponse()
Dim myreader As New System.IO.StreamReader(myResp.GetResponseStream)
WebResponse = myreader.ReadToEnd()

MsgBox(WebResponse)
```

Comment: Couple things.  Firstly WebRequest & HttpWebRequest are pretty much obsolete now, you should really consider moving to HttpClient, that alone probably won't make much difference to your problem though.  Next, "Bad Request" simply means just that (Although I've seen it miss used somewhat by various services).  Something in the call you are making does not meet the requirement of the service you're attempting to consume.   Could be headers or body of your request is formatted wrong.  Get it working in tools like postman 1st, then replicate to code

Comment: Hey Hursey, thanks for taking the time to respond and share some suggestions! You're right about not using the now deprecated HttpWebRequest and even though it probably won't make a difference, I am most likely going to change this over to HttpClient. I also found out that I need to properly serialize the JSON data before sending it, so I'm in the process of trying to implement Newtonsoft.JSON to do that now as well. Thanks for suggesting postman, I'll check that out as it looks like this is going to be more difficult than I initially thought and I want to try and get it working in that first.

Comment: For future reference in debugging such situations, you might also consider pulling [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) out of your toolbox.

Comment: Does it say you have to pass `username:token` as a base64 encoded string? -- Set `Option Strict` to `ON` right away, what you see after that is what you have to fix (suggestion: use `WebRequest.CreateHttp([URL])` to create the request). The `HttpWebResponse` (you need to cast the `WebResponse` to this Type) is disposable, hence you need to declare it with an `Using` statement, as all the streams that are generated in the process -- Possibly, as mentioned, move to HttpClient